# elinks reports `Bad HTTP response` in Mac OS

Tags: macos, homebrew, elinks

I just installed `elinks` via `brew install elinks` in my Macbook. When I open http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html in `elinks`, it reports `Bad HTTP response`. Then I tried the same web address with `elinks` in Debian 8, it works fine.

What's wrong with `elinks` in OSX?

Comment: Same problem with http://tiddlywiki.com/ Bug in elinks?

Comment: Yes. Do you know how to solve it ?

Comment: I used curl (or wget) to download the file and then opened the local file in elinks.

Comment: But, it is a litter uncnvenient.

Comment: It is known issue. See http://minimul.com/elinks-browser-not-working-using-brew-install.html for the workaround.

Answer (score 4):

This is apparently a bug in stable `elinks` version 0.11.

Install development version of `elinks` (0.12pre6 at the moment), it works fine:

```
brew install --devel elinks
```

Comment: This is now `brew install --HEAD elinks` in the latest version of Homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem happened to me. But it seems to work after I reinstalled elinks.

If you already installed the normal version, just do

> brew remove elinks

and

> brew install --devel elinks

This should fix the problem.